# Electron - WebView - chrome is obsolete

Tags: webview, electron

I have created a custom browser with a webview tag.
When i navigate in google.it (or google.com), sometimes appears a message with say that chrome is obsolete.
My app versions are :

Node.js 8.9.3 
Chromium 61.0.3163.100 
Electron 2.0.2

attached an image of the alert (sorry but it is in Italian)

Is It possible to remove this warning?

Thanks
Jempis

[the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGQi8.png)

EDIT
I found a workaround for remove the warning:

i set the option

```
useragent
```

a different of chrome, for example

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"
```

And the warning doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

Electron is not intended as Browser, it's for using web technology in desktop apps. Due to that, it does not always use the newest Chrome engine version.

The warning is shown by Google (the website). You could modify the user agent header to pretend a newer Chome engine version or an other Browser, see https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag.

`<webview src="https://www.github.com/" useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0"></webview>`

However, that won't fix the problem of delayed security updates.

Comment: Hi jonas, thanks for the response. I understood that the problem is that the chrome engine is not always updated, I was hoping for a workaround to remove this warning, is It possible?

Comment: thanks @Jonas, 
i know that don't fix the problem of delayed security updates, but I wanted a workaround like this..